# Adding products with same configurable attributes to cart

Tags: magento2

I am trying to add products with identical configurable attributes, but with different values of a custom option

```
<input class="swatch-input" name="super_attribute[left][151]" value="" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute; left:-1000px">
<input class="swatch-input" name="super_attribute[right][151]" value="" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" style="visibility: hidden; position:absolute; left:-1000px">
```

**\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add**

```
$options = $params['options'][1];
$attributes = $params['super_attribute'];

foreach ($options AS $key => $option) {

    $storeId = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
    $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($params['product']);

    $attribute = '';
    $value = '';
    $params['options'] = array();
    $params['super_attribute'] = array();

//  left = 1 - right = 2
    $params['options'][1][0] = $option;

    if ($key == 0) {
        $attribute = $attributes['left'];
    }

    if ($key == 1) {
        $attribute = $attributes['right'];
    }

    foreach ($attribute AS $attrid => $value) {
        $params['super_attribute'][$attrid] = $value;
    }

    $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);

}

$this->cart->save();
```

*Array ( [super_attribute] => Array ( [90] => 5 ) [qty] => 2 [options][1][0] => 1)*

*Array ( [super_attribute] => Array ( [90] => 5 ) [qty] => 4 )[options][1][0] => 2)*

**Then i get a mysql error:**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento2`.`quote_item_option`, CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_OPTION_ITEM_ID_QUOTE_ITEM_ITEM_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) REFERENCES `quote_item` (`item_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `quote_item_option` (`product_id`, `code`, `value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Can anybody help me

Comment: Did you got the reason behind this? I too am facing similar issue